# WPF как работать с многопоточностью?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть следующий код:

```
private async void btnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int redirectCount = Convert.ToInt32(RedirectCount.Text);
    int return_Count = 0; // Количество вызовов reg_link  
    reg_short_link reg_short_link = new reg_short_link();

    for (int i = 0; i < redirectCount; i++)
    {
        string result = await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(
            () => reg_short_link.reg_link(redirectCount),
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        this.result_link.Text = result + "\n";
    }
}
```

`reg_short_link.reg_link(redirectCount)` выполняет определенные действия и возвращает строку которую мне нужно записать в `result_link.Text`.

В такой реализации все работает, что я хочу сделать:
Метод `reg_link(redirectCount)` нужно выполнить определенное количество  (redirectCount) раз.
Нужно выполнить метод одновременно в большом количестве потоков (например в 50) при этом каждый раз при выполнении записать ответ в `result_link.Text`.
Как это сделать?

Comment: Во первых, `void` замените на `Task`, а лучше `Task<string>` и сделайте нормальную задачу! Во вторых, научитесь работать с привязками, отвяжите данные от контрола, ибо ваш `this.result_link.Text =  result + "\n";` может сыграть с вами злую шутку как по производительности, так и по "данные в другом потоке". Ну а так, есть например [Parallel](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for), который думаю подойдет под вашу задачу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `RoutedEventHandler` - это `void`, его не сделать `Task`

Comment: @aepot Я про то, что генерирует текст, должно быть `SomeStringProperty = await GenerateString();`, то есть вся логика формирования текста должна быть в отдельной задаче (`Task<string>`). Ну и команды не отменяли...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласен с @EvgeniyZ, привязки `Binding` в WPF - это сама суть WPF. Рекомендую вам с ними ознакомиться. Можете зайти в мой профиль, там больше половины ответов про WPF, MVVM и привязки. На англоязычном SO тоже.

Вот вам решение по многопоточности, или если быть точнее, многозадачности

```csharp
private async void btnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnStart.IsEnabled = false; // кнопку лучше отключить, пока идет работа

    int redirectCount = Convert.ToInt32(RedirectCount.Text);
    int return_Count = 0; // Количество вызовов reg_link  
    reg_short_link reg_short_link = new reg_short_link();

    int maxConcurrentTasks = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2; // можно 50, но обычно делают так
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrentTasks);
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s => result_link.Text += s + Environment.NewLine);
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < redirectCount; i++)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // если больше чем maxConcurrentTasks, то ждем
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            string result = reg_short_link.reg_link(redirectCount);
            progress.Report(result);
            semaphore.Release();
        })); 
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); 
    // все задачи завершены
    btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

- `SemaphoreSlim` - светофор, позволяет ограничить количество одновременно входящих в его зону задач
- `IProgress` - колбэк, выполняемый в контексте синхронизации того потока, в котором был создан `Progress`, то есть потокобезопасный вариант отправить что-то из параллельной задачи в интерфейс.

Будьте осторожны, если метод `reg_link` пишет куда-то данные, он должен быть потокобезопасным, иначе данные можно повредить, так как несколько параллельно выполняемых методов могу писать одновременно в одно и то же место. Если у вас там например `Dictionary` с этими строчками, то рассмотрите вариант с заменой на `ConcurrentDictionary`, либо используйте `lock()` для небезопасных фрагментов кода.

Или покажите этот метод (или вообще весь класс) в вопросе, я перепишу.

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!
reg_link  отправляет запрос на сервер, в многопоточном (многозадачном) режиме и несколько потоков иногда получают один и тот же ответ, использую lock(), но тогда скорость работы заметно падает

Comment: @ВадимГоменюк значит вы неправильно используете `lock()`. В любом случае, я вас предупредил. Если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста отметьте его принятым.